# AWS code deploy on on-premises instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

I'm trying to test AWS CodeDeploy on an On-Premises instances. I was successfully able to register, install and configure CodeDeploy on my instance. When I tried adding it to the Deployment group under on-premises instances it never showed up.

I have tagged the instance.

There's this note that I found on [Use the register-on-premises-instance Command (IAM Session ARN) to Register an On-Premises Instance - AWS CodeDeploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/register-on-premises-instance-iam-session-arn.html) which might seem relevant to my problem. But I'm not able to figure it out yet.

> If you reuse an AWS CodeDeploy service role as part of creating a deployment group that targets on-premises instances, you must include Tag:get* to the Action portion of the service role's policy statement.

**Edit**

I tried creating a service role with action `Tag:get*` but with no luck, since it kept on complaining that

```
AssumeRole policy may only specify STS AssumeRole actions.
```

**Edit-2**

So, the link above was asking to attach a policy under the IAM menu to the service role with `tag:Get*`. I tried doing that, still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the On-Premises instance never shows up in the GUI for the Codedeploy. But if you try to deploy the application on a separate test group (or the same) with the On-premises instance tags same as the one you have for your instance. It will be deployed successfully.

The only thing that needs to be taken care of is adding a new service policy given in the note below:

> If you reuse an AWS CodeDeploy service role as part of creating a deployment group that targets on-premises instances, you must include Tag:get* to the Action portion of the service role's policy statement.